# Rails 5.1.2 - form_with is not showing data-remote="true" in the html

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, forms

Rails 5.1.2:

I'm trying to create an AJAX form using [form_with](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_with) in line with the [Rails documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#built-in-helpers) and [this GitHub thread](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/25197).

This code:

```
<%= form_with url: '/' do |f| %>
<% end %>
```

and in fact this code:

```
<%= form_with url: '/', remote: true do |f| %>
<% end %>
```

both produce this html:

```
<form action="/" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post">
  <input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="..." />
  <input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="..." />
</form>
```

Why isn't `data-remote="true"` appearing in the HTML, as the first link I have posted indicates it should, and how do I get it to appear?

Comment: what happend if you change `url: '/'` to `url: root_path`?

Comment: makes no difference.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Default value for `data-remote` is configured by option `Rails.application.config.action_view.form_with_generates_remote_forms`. By default in Rails 5 this option is `true`. Search this through all your project, it seems that you migrated from Rails 4 or smth. else with overriding this option.

Comment: Suspect this is the correct answer because, as you rightly say, I upgraded and can see this option (found in config/initializers/new_framework_defaults_5_1.rb) is set to false.  Will mark as correct once confirmed.

Comment: I cannot find `form_with_generates_remote_forms` anywhere in my project in Rails 5.1.6 (including `config/initializers` or checking the above-mentioned option in the Rails console). Any hints on where else it could be or if the variable has been renamed?

Answer (score 18):

I was having the same problem with a Rails 5.1.4 app. Using `local: false` fixed the problem.

```js
<%= form_with url: '/', local: false do |f| %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: This problem showed up in Rails 6 and this same solution fixed it.

Comment: Can confirm @RajeshM comment. Had the same problem with `gem 'rails', '~> 6.1.1'`

Answer (score 4):

In *Rails 5.1.2* By default, `form_with` assumes that your form will be using Ajax. You can opt out of this behavior by passing the `:local` option in `form_with`.

```
<%= form_with url: '/' do |f| %>
<% end %>
```

Above code produces

```
<form action="/" accept-charset="UTF-8" data-remote="true" method="post">
  <input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="..." />
  <input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="..." />
</form>
```

Also If you want to use form without ajax, you can use below way -

```
<%= form_with url: '/', local: true do |f| %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: as you can see, this is not what happens for OP

Comment: I didn't understand what you want to say ?
I checked above code and it worked.
@SergioTulentsev

Comment: `data-remote: "true"`, it's not generated for the OP

Comment: You can read this documentation specially section - (3.1.1. form_with)
http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html

Answer (score 4):

For me the addition these two lines to `config/application.rb` fixed it:

```
# Initialize configuration defaults for originally generated Rails version.
config.load_defaults 5.2
```

Answer (score 1):

It will happen in Rails 5.1

With my config in new_framework_defaults_5_1.rb like this:

```
# Make `form_with` generate non-remote forms.
Rails.application.config.action_view.form_with_generates_remote_forms = false
```

And in my view file, I'm using like this:

```
= form_with(model: your_model , url: your_path, method: :post, local: false) do |f|
....your input here...
```

Now your html code will generate data-remote: true in your form.