# How to make Rails 5.2 form submit remotely?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my view, using Slim:

```
= form_with url: update_pn_price_path(@price)
  .form-group
    = label_tag :part_number
    = text_field_tag :part_number, @price.part_number, required: true

  .form-group
    => submit_tag t(:save), class: 'btn btn-primary btn-sm'
    = link_to 'Cancel', '', class: 'btn btn-link btn-sm', data: { cancel_in_place: true }
```

This always submits using a standard submit, not remotely. Log shows:

```
Processing by PricesController#update_pn as HTML
```

What am I doing wrong? Why won't it submit using JS?

Comment: You have to add `remote: true` to the Form

Comment: No, I don't. The `form_with` function automatically adds that. But I've added it just to be sure there's not some glitch with that, and it still doesn't submit remotely.

Comment: Is this a valid syntax in slim `=> submit_tag`? just asking.

Comment: @Pavan I believe so. Results in `<input type="submit" name="commit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" data-disable-with="Save">`

Comment: @croceldon make sure `form_with` generates right html in the browser with `data-remote="true"`, inspect it.

Comment: @7urkm3n I did before I posted here. the data attribute is present.

Comment: @croceldon Don't see your post related to that!

Comment: Did you upgrade your app from a previous version? Might be worth checking this post out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45221800/rails-5-1-2-form-with-is-not-showing-data-remote-true-in-the-html/45305004

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's what solved the issue. Rookie mistake, but posting here in case someone else runs into it.

My form shown above was inside another form. You can submit such an 'inner' form, but not remotely. The form was being inserted via an AJAX call, so I changed that to insert to the end of the HTML body, and then positioned using CSS. That put it outside the containing form and made things work as expected.

Comment: +1 for posting the actual solution to your issue. That was impossible to spot without some more context.

Answer (score 5):

I'm surprised to see that your view compiles. There are a few problems that I can spot.

1. You start indenting content as though it would be in the form. However you didn't open a form tag or provided a block to the *form_with* method.

   > ```
   > = form_with url: update_pn_price_path(@price)
   >   .form-group
   > ```

   Should at least be changed to:

   ```
   = form_with url: update_pn_price_path(@price) do
     .form-group
   ```

   Since a variable is provided to a block, the preferred way is to capture it in a variable (`form` in the code below). If you're not planning to use it you should still capture it in an underscored variable to indicate that it is there, but not being used (`_form`).

   ```
   = form_with url: update_pn_price_path(@price) do |form|
     .form-group
   ```
2. Since you're using a form builder, the preferred way of creating elements is through the form builder interface. Since you're not creating the submit tag through the form builder this might be another reason why the submit isn't done remotely.

   I would at least replace:

   > ```
   > => submit_tag t(:save), class: 'btn btn-primary btn-sm'
   > ```

   With:

   ```
   = form.submit t('save'), class: 'btn btn-primary btn-sm'
   ```

   But preferably update the whole form to use the form builder. The result should look something like this:

   ```
   = form_with model: @price, url: update_pn_price_path(@price) do |form|
     .form-group
       = form.label :part_number
       = form.text_field :part_number, required: true

     .form-group
       = form.submit t('save'), class: 'btn btn-primary btn-sm'
       = link_to 'Cancel', '', class: 'btn btn-link btn-sm', data: {cancel_in_place: true}
   ```

For more/other form builder methods see the [*FormBuilder*](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder.html) and [*FormHelper*](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html) documentation.