# Upgrading to rails 5.2 - remote forms now refreshing the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ujs

I am trying to upgrade a Rails 5.1.7 application to 5.2.0. Some forms on the site were broken by the upgrade. The template for the form looks like this:

```
<%= form_with model: record, url: client_field_value_path(@dataset, record), remote: true do |form| %>
  <%= the form contents %>
<% end %>
```

I think the only relevant part of the form is that it uses `remote: true`. I have found out that in Rails 5.2 `remote: true` was changed to the default for the `form_with` helper. I believe this is implemented with unobtrusive javascript, but I don't understand ujs very well.

The form is meant to be submitted without reloading the page, and the state changes in-page are handled with ajax listeners. We use jquery - the client-side code includes the line:

```
  $(this.form).trigger('submit');
```

which is now performing a *local* submission, and not a remote one. So the page refreshes, and the JSON response gets rendered. I found [an issue raised against rails-ujs](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/29546#issuecomment-313981539) which looks relevant, and they suggest replacing `$(form).submit()` by

```
form = document.querySelector('form');
form.dispatchEvent(new Event('submit', {bubbles: true}));
```

or, with rails-ujs,

```
form = document.querySelector('form');
Rails.fire(form, 'submit');
```

I have added `rails-ujs` to my `application.js` file:

```
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js, which will include all the files
// listed below.
// ....
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require rails-ujs
// ....
```

(jquery and jquery_ujs were already there). I tried both of the suggestions above and neither of them seems to trigger a submission of the form. I'm really stuck! If there's any more detail I can provide, please ask. I don't understand the situation with ujs very well, so I'm a bit lost.

**EDIT:** Full body of the save call - this is triggered when a "save" button is clicked (but that button is not `<input type=submit>`, it's just a styled button).

```
  save(event) {
    if( event ) {
      event.preventDefault();
      event.stopPropagation();
    }

    this.container.addClass('saving');

    // this.form.submit();
    Rails.fire(this.form[0], 'submit');


    this.container.find(".field-controls button").prop('disabled', true);
  }
```

**Update:** I have managed to get it working. I would really appreciate some help understanding where the following changes came from, and whether something is broken in my application config that's making it harder than necessary.

- Explicitly changed `remote: true` to `local: false` in the form.
- - Without this, the `data-remote=true` attribute is not set in the HTML.
- - Leaving it blank is not enough, despite the fact that it should be the default. If I don't provide `local: false` I get in the console:

```
$('form[data-remote=true]').length
0
```

- - According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48381623/14421936) the default value is configured by `Rails.application.config.action_view.form_with_generates_remote_forms`. This value is `nil` for me in the console. I can't find anywhere it's overridden.
- Added `rails-ujs` and removed `jquery_ujs` in my JS assets.
- - I needed to include `rails-ujs` in order for `Rails` to be defined (needed for the next step).
- - When including `rails-ujs`, I got a JS warning that `jquery_ujs` should be removed. I think this is included by the `jquery-rails` gem - am I safe to remove that, too?
- Changed `this.form.submit()` to `Rails.fire(this.form[0], 'submit')`.
- - Any variant of `$(form).submit()` performs a local submission and not a remote one.
- - In previous versions, the jQuery submission was remote and not local.
- - I don't know anywhere where this is documented. [The answer](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/29546#issuecomment-313981539) I linked above explains it - but is this really the way RoR intends for you to submit ajax forms? I find it *extremely* unintuitive that there is a "right way" and a "wrong way" to submit forms in this sense.
- Changed the signature of the `ajax:success` handler.
- - Likewise, I didn't find anywhere where this change was explained, but I guess it's just "how rails-ujs does it". I had to change by ajax handler from

```
  form.on('ajax:success', (event, response, status) => {
    $.each(response, (i, key) => {
      do_stuff();
    });
  });
```

to

```
  form.on('ajax:success', (event) => {
    const [response, _status, _xhr] = event.detail;
    $.each(response, (i, key) => {
      do_stuff();
    });
  });
```

Again, I guess this is because the event is handled by rails-ujs and not by jquery, but... why? How are you supposed to know?

Comment: Do you have the preventDefault in your jquery?

Comment: Don't go to the beta, go to the first released version - you may be fighting a fixed bug already. Just make sure you are following the official update instructions, and go version by version.

Comment: @Int'lManOfCodingMystery I've added the full body of the `save()` call (which is meant to submit the form). It's triggered on click of a button which is not the submit button of the form (I don't know why). In fact I went to check the caller and no event is passed in, so I don't think this block does anything. I don't think there is anywhere that is causing `preventDefault` on the submit event - is that what you meant?

Comment: @BradWerth That's a good point, thank you. I've redone the upgrade to 5.2.0 instead and I'm seeing the same behaviour. I'll change it in the question to avoid confusion. I did try to read [the upgrade notes](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html#upgrading-from-rails-5-1-to-rails-5-2) but didn't find anything that helped.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, so a couple of things hop to mind.

### local: false  instead of remote: true

First of all, `form_with` doesn't have a `remote` option anymore, it's called local:

```
<%= form_with model: record, url: client_field_value_path(@dataset, record), local: false do |form| %>
  <%= the form contents %>
<% end %>
```

Also, you should be able to skip this altogether because it's the default. You can confirm this by removing it and then inspecting the html markup for the route pointing to this form view and you should see `data-remote="true"` within the form tag. This probably isn't the problem.

### Where is your jQuery code?

Usually, the way ujs works is you'd have a file in your views directory called `create.js.erb`. The js in that file will run when you submit the form and you'll be able to use erb tags within that template to add dynamic content to the JS. For example, you can use `render` here to render a partial and pass in an instance variable defined in the controller.

Of course, if you've got all your javascript set up separately and it should only work properly with your javascript engaged, then it's no longer UJS. UJS stands for unobtrusive javascript. The idea is that the javascript enhances functionality rather than replacing it. This means that if your javascript didn't load for some reason, the form would still submit and work properly without javascript engaged. This may not be the case for your app, and that's fine, but it would be useful to know to provide a better answer.

The way the UJS pattern works relies on some controller code. So you'd have a `respond_to` block in your controller that would respond both to requests for html and requests for js. If the form is remote, then it will run the javascript in the file matching the controller action. For example,

```rb
def create 
  @record = Record.new(record_params)
  respond_to do |format|
    if @record.save
      format.html { redirect_to records_path }
      format.js {}
    else 
      format.html { render :new }
      format.js { render :error }
    end
  end
end
end
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It's helped me make some progress - I'll answer the part that helped first. The first bug I noticed was that `$('form[data-remote=true]')` was no longer returning any forms, where it had before. I misunderstood the idea that remote was "the default" to mean that this attribute was no longer used. When I have `remote: true` in the view, or if it's blank, then `$('form[data-remote=true]')` is empty. When I set `local: false`, however, that returns the form. Now when I click the form, it gets submitted to the server. ATM the form hangs, but I can investigate further.

Comment: We are *not* using Javascript in the way you describe. There is a folder `app/assets/javacripts/modules` which contains several (~10) ad-hoc scripts which are all loaded on every page. There isn't much JS in the app (and this is the most complex application of it).

In this particular controller there is only a JS response. So when I trigger a local submission, I get an undesirable plaintext page with JSON content.

Comment: I managed to patch myself to a solution that appears to be working. I don't really understand why the changes I've made work / are necessary. You seem to understand the situation much more clearly, so if you have any advice regarding the changes I've made above, I'd really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

I now understand the issue! I was previously very confused.

### The answer

For some reason (which I still don't understand),

```
Rails.application.config.action_view.form_with_generates_remote_forms
```

was unset following the upgrade. Because it was unset, the `data-remote="true"` attribute was not present in the HTML, so jquery-ujs was not submitting the form with AJAX. Setting this config variable to true in my initialization fixed the issue.

### Digression

I got very confused thinking that `rails-ujs` was a drop-in replacement for `jquery-ujs`. It is not. They work in very different ways! jquery-ujs intercepts events called through jquery to (for example) get remote forms to be submitted with AJAX. rails-ujs has the same functional effect by creating its own events and calling them with `Rails.fire`. They don't play well together!

All the confusion I got after adding rails-ujs stems from the fact that they are basically different libraries with different APIs.